# Spring REST service with third party api as a datasource

Tags: spring, api

I need to expose REST service which as a datasource gets data returned from third party api calls, instead of regular DB.

I'd like to have all the benefits of the Spring Data Rest, but I don't know what I really need as my dependency, since I'm not using JPA.
Basicaly, how my model (Entity?) should be implemented to have the functionalities (like, paging, sorting...).
What Spring framework dependencies should I choose.

Or possibly I'm overlooking something here and for such requirement is another path.
Thanks.

Comment: DataSource , Conncetion, Statement, Transaction are all interfaces. You can add your own implementation for them which just delegates the logic to the api calls

Comment: That is, all work is to do the same implementation as JdbcTemplate does?